# How can I speed up this array multiplication?

Tags: matlab, optimization, multidimensional-array, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

```
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:M
        for c = 1:3
            A(:,:,c,i) = A(:,:,c,i).*B(:,:,j);
        end
    end
end
```

Is it possible to eliminate the innermost loop by vectorization, for instance?

Comment: Is your code correct? The `j` loop is useless, only the value `j=M` survives. With your code as it stands, you could remove the second loop and just set `j=M;`

Comment: Oh, the `j` loop is okay, variable names were incorrect and I fixed it now, thanks.

Comment: Same problem. Only `j=M` is really used! The results of the other values of `j` are _overwritten_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can eliminate the loop over j by pre-multiplying the matrix:

```
B2 = prod(B, 3); % Element-wise product along third dim

for i = 1:N
    for c = 1:3
        A(:,:,c,i) = A(:,:,c,i) .* B2;
    end
end
```

Then you can use repmat to tile the Matrix B2 out and eliminate the other two loops. I have some difficulty wrapping my head around 4D-Matricies, but it should look like this:

```
B2 = prod(B, 3); % Element-wise product along third dim
B3 = repmat(B2, [1 1 3 N]);
A = A .* B3;
```

Or (even better) use bsxfun:

```
B2 = prod(B, 3); % Element-wise product along third dim
A = bsxfun(@times, A, B2);
```

bsxfun will use less memory because it "virtually replicates" B2.

Comment: Well, that's not the same, it would be same if `B2` was inside the `i` loop and looked like this `B2 = prod(B(:,:,i-1), 3);` that should speed up the program thank you for that but now how do I use repmat for this?

Comment: @ĬnfernalSeraphím: Besides floating point precision errors, the output is the same. On a mathematical level, the code does exactly the same.

Comment: I would use `A=bsxfun(@times,A,B2);` instead of `repmat`

Comment: Indeed, that's probably the better thing to do. I have incorporated that ;-)